# Receive array of value from POST and again POST that array of values to other form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

Am having three forms, I need to post values from form 1 to form2 and again combine form 1 and form 2 i want to post the value to form 3.

Form 1 and Form 2 having array of values..

I can able to receive array of values from form 1 to form 2. but not able to POST that form 1 and form 2 array of value to form 3.

Am working on PHP.

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: You could save form 1 / 2 in `$_SESSION` variables, or as hidden form (form 1 in form 2, form 1 and 2 in form 3) elements, or ... (any other options)

Comment: Why don't you use sessions?

Comment: SESSION would be better, posted values will appear in page source on form2 which isn't secure.

Comment: Yes, I use hidden text field to pass array of values from form 1 to form 2. But again from 2 to form 3 i need to pass array of value from form 1 and array of value from form 2 to form 3. --- But form 1 having 30 fields and form 2 having 30 fields.. So receiving form 1 value to form 2 is achieved. Again I need to pass form 1 array of value to form 3 - Am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use the **Hidden fields** .
First form $_POST value to be the second value Hidden field. After You submit the second form You Get both form 1 and form 2 Data's

Or 
 Use **Session** also a good Approach

Answer (score 1):

Use session or hidden fields but using session would be better let me explain

```
using Hidden :-
```

Form1:-
data submitted/posted on form 2 :- get post values in hidden on your second form

Form 2:-
all form 2 input fields+ form1 hidden fields and post to form 3

Get all posted values of form1 and 2 on form 3

```
**Using Session**
```

Form1:-
data submitted :- make a session and store all values of form1 in session

Form 2:-
data submitted :- make a session and store all values of form1 in session

Form 3:- Retrieve values of sessions of form1 and form2

Comment: thanks I used the session to store the value and post to post the content